# Performance of a class containing many instance methods

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I started learning C# with unity about 2 years ago. Along the way, I have a class that contains miscellaneous methods that I use frequently. Every time I need to call a certain method, I just create an instance of the class and call the method I need.

Now it has grown in to about 4000 lines. I use this class as often as I use 'Mathf' so you can imagine this is allover my projects. I create an instance of the class even If i only need one of the methods.

will this have an effect on the performance of my app? so far I don't see any performance issue, but maybe I just don't see it. Maybe my app could be performing better if I fix this.

Comment: Please tell my you can make your methods `static` or are already doing so. Because it WILL effect performance if you just create instance and leave them for the GC to clean up later.

Comment: Making them static maybe a solution (albeit it would mean I have to edit codes all around my project). Honestly didn't think of that. Also I stayed away from static because of numerous tutorials that said avoid static classes.

Comment: I don't know of any reason to avoid static classes. Static methods even less so. The entire point is to provide methods that can be used without creating an instance. Generally, you should always make your methods static given the opportunity where they don't access instance members.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. Ideas are just coming to me now. This just solves everything. I  just started leaning and using static classes a few months ago (just because I didn't have any other choice at the time).

Comment: I suppose criticism towards statics is that A) you can't inherit from them and B) static members are basically global variables. However, if all you do is some calculations with the passed arguments (e.g. some `Math.Sqrt` or what have you) then they should be perfectly fine. Definitely better than creating instances and discarding them later.

Comment: Yes i agree. I got the habbit of collecting methods when i was using VBA. I didnt have problem with global variables back then

Answer (score 3):

Making the methods static will reduce some of the performance hit related to GC.

A class with 4000 lines of miscellaneous methods is not going to be following most principles of OOP or general best practice. It may be worth looking through the class and splitting it down into areas of functionality if possible.